# How to add the all columns data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i am working on a project in which i need to Sum the columns data by query, the columns contains the working hours.

or is there any other way/solution to do this ...?

[image: here are the hours in data base for all tasks]

[image: table structure]

Comment: What you have tried so far

Comment: mysql sum() Group By http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: select sum(hours) FROM .... ?

Comment: Did you not Google `mysql sum` first? The answer is literally in your question *"which i need to Sum the columns data"*

Comment: SELECT SUM(hours) AS total FROM tasks;

Comment: SELECT SUM(hours) AS total FROM tasks WHERE DATE(end_date) >= '2014-01-12' AND DATE(end_date) <= '2014-01-13';

Comment: SELECT SUM(hours) AS total FROM tasks WHERE DATE(end_date) = '2014-01-12';

Comment: nice idea to add end and start date in where. thanks @Ali

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you got some choices...

**Total hours entire table**

```
select 
  sum(hours)
from
  tasks;
```

**Total hours per end date**

```
select 
  end_date, sum(hours)
from
  tasks
group by end_date;
```

**Total spended hours per project**

```
select 
  project_id, sum(hours)
from
  tasks
group by project_id;
```

**Total spended hours per employee**

```
select 
  emp_id, sum(hours)
from
  tasks
group by emp_id;
```

**Total spended hours per employee per project**

```
select 
  project_id,emp_id, sum(hours)
from
  tasks
group by project_id,emp_id;
```

I think you got it :)

You could of course add a where clause, e.g. `where start_date between` ... or `end_date =`

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT sum(hours) FROM tableName.
```

Answer (score 1):

use (`sum`) mysql  aggregate function:

```
SELECT sum(hours) FROM tasks
```

Here is good tutorial:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx

Answer (score -2):

If you want to count total hours per Project, you need to do the following

```
select *,sum(hours) as totalHours from tasks
group by project_id
```

You may **omit the group by clause** if you want to sum all your hours in your table.

This works also with other aggregate functions such as group_concat(),min,max and so on ([Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)).